# Plotting a meshgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot a `meshgrid` over `X_test` data but when I run the code the following exception appears:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 196548 and the array at index 1 has size 14550

The variable `xx` has to do with all the problems but I cannot see the way to solve the issue.

```
classifier = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(),
                               max_samples = 10,
                               n_estimators = 100)

X0, X1 = X_test.iloc[:,0], X_test.iloc[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)


def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=0.02):
 
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h), sparse=True)
    return xx, yy
 
def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
 
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
     
    return out

 
# Pass the data. make_meshgrid will automatically identify the min and max points to draw the grid
plot_contours(plt, classifier, xx, yy,
                  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,
                  alpha=0.8)

# plot the meshgrid
plt.scatter(X0, X1, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=20, edgecolors='k', alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your question with the full error trace. Also, question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

This part is causing problems:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h), sparse=True)
```

You get that error because it does not default to your two columns when you set `sparse=True`, you can compare:

```
_x,_y = np.meshgrid([0.1,0.2,0.3],[1,2])
len(_x.ravel()),len(_y.ravel())
(6, 6)

_x,_y = np.meshgrid([0.1,0.2,0.3],[1,2],sparse=True)
len(_x.ravel()),len(_y.ravel())
(3, 2)
```

Not very sure if it is realistic to plot so many points, so if you don't return sparse:

```
def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=0.2):
 
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    
    return xx, yy

def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
 
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
     
    return out
```

Then using an example dataset, we plot:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=2,
                            n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                            random_state=0, shuffle=False)

classifier = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(),
                               max_samples = 10,
                               n_estimators = 100)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(X[:50,])
y_train = y[:50]

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

X_test = pd.DataFrame(X[:50,])
y_test = y[50:]
 
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X_test.iloc[:,0], X_test.iloc[:, 1])

plot_contours(plt, classifier, xx, yy,
                  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,
                  alpha=0.8)

plt.scatter(X0, X1, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=20, edgecolors='k', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]